# Differently sized nested brackets in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

I would like to be able to render brackets of different sizes, so that the inner nested ones are smaller than the enclosing ones.

[LaTeX supports this](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Brackets_and_Parentheses#/Reference_guide), is there a way to do it in MathJax?

Comment: See [the local LaTeX/MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it wasn't there - I just added it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX seems to be happy with \Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr), $$\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)$$

Comment: That is aesthetically pleasing.